# Find 3x3 Matrix with specific eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have to find a 3x3 matrix `M` with only one given eigenvalue `λ = 0` and an eigenvector `v = (1,1,1)`. These should be the only solutions for the matrix.

How do I do that? Which relations should I use?

Comment: Hint: write the definition for an eigenvector-eigenvalue pair. If zero is an eigenvalue, then...

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you for the direction, but I'm still unsure, should I use of the fact that M*x = λ*x? Or that (M-λI) * x = 0? Or that the det(M-λI) = 0? Or that the matrix is not invertible and is singular?

Answer (score 1):

If $(\lambda, x)$ is an eigenpair of $M$ then we indeed have $Mx = \lambda x.$ But $\lambda = 0$ in the given eigenpair, so we must have $Mx = 0.$ That is, $x \in \mathrm{Nul} \ M$ (the null space). Now we know the given eigenvector $v = (1, 1, 1)$ must be in this null space.

We should note that there are infinitely many $M$ that satisfy your given conditions. To get an equivalence class, think of the simple case where the matrix you want is in row echelon form. Form a simple relation with the entries of this eigenvector, say $2v_1 - v_2 - v_3 = 0$ and you'll have that a row in your matrix should be $(2, -1, -1).$ Thus, one such $M$ is

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Check by multiplying and finding the eigenvalues!

Comment: But wouldn't there be also an eigenvalue of 2 for the matrix M, because we don't have zeros on the diagonal?

Comment: True, yes, but this is just a "reduced case" where you have the one known eigenpair. If that is the only properties the matrix must have, then the only such $M$ is the zero matrix.